# How do you programmatically add an LDAP account on an Android mobile device?

Tags: java, android, ldap

I know I can manually go into the settings to add an LDAP account onto my Android phone but I am working on deploying a solution to clients who will not be tech-savy enough to manually enter the LDAP settings on their devices to connect to our LDAP server.  All I need to do is have a way to programatically enter the LDAP settings on the user's device so the LDAP settings will show up on the device under their account:

[image]

I don't need an LDAP connector, I don't need to setup an LDAP account on the server, I just need a way to create the account connection settings on the client device (Android phone).  I will already have the connection settings handy.

Comment: I am guessing this may have something to do with AccountManager but I am not sure: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html